# Loop saving only the last DataFrame in a csv file

Tags: python, pandas

I would like each iterated dataframe to be saved in the csv file, but only the last one gets saved. Please advise, what am I doing wrong in the below code?

```
inverterdata=[]
    for i in invertersinfo.items():
        inverterdata.append([i[0],i[1]])
        invdata=pd.DataFrame(inverterdata)
        data = pd.json_normalize(json.loads(invdata.to_json(orient="records")))
        hh=data.explode('1.telemetries')                         
        data2 = pd.json_normalize(json.loads(hh.to_json(orient="records")))  
        data2 = data2.drop(['1.count', '0'], axis=1)
        #data2.columns = data2.columns.str.replace(r'1.telemetries.', '')
        data2.columns = [col.replace('1.telemetries.', '') for col in data2.columns]
        data2.columns += "_"+ name
        print(data2)
```

```
`
final = []
inverterdata=[]
for i in invertersinfo.items():
    inverterdata.append([i[0],i[1]])
    invdata=pd.DataFrame(inverterdata)
    data = pd.json_normalize(json.loads(invdata.to_json(orient="records")))
    data2 = data.explode('1.telemetries')                         
    data2 = pd.json_normalize(json.loads(hh.to_json(orient="records")))  
    data2 = data2.drop(['1.count', '0'], axis=1) 
    data2.columns = [col.replace('1.telemetries.', '') for col in data2.columns]
    data2.columns += "_"+ name
    final.append(data2)
    print(final)`
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure to understand what your code is trying to do but I guess your are dynamically creating dataframe fron json files. If they all have the same structure, you could create an empty dataframe prior to your for loop like: `my_df = pd.DataFrame()` and within your loop after all your data transformations, you could use `pd.concat([my_df, data2])` ?
After all the iterations, you will get a big dataframe and you can export it to a csv easily.